# Как распарсить данные из запроса fetch?

Tags: javascript, fetch, render

Задача довольно простая, но никак не могу получить данные из запроса fetch.
Есть файл со скриптом который должен возвращать разметку по итогу запроса через fetch.
Если выводить данные через консоль console.dir(fetchAll); - то выдает массив необходимых объектов, но при рендере выходит ошибка:
"Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."
Вопрос - как отрендерить данные по итогам fetch запроса?
Спасибо
Ниже код:

```
const BASE_URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

const fetchAllPosts = () => {
  return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/posts`).then(response => {
    return response.json();
  });
};

export default async function PostList() {

let fetchAll = await fetchAllPosts();
console.dir(fetchAll);

return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {fetchAll.map(post => (
          <li key={post.id}>
            <Post title={post.title} body={post.body} />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
export default function PostList() {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchAllPosts().then(res => setPosts(res));
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {posts.map(post => (
                    <li key={post.id}>
                         <Post title={post.title} body={post.body} />
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: спасибо dresser, все работает!